# Database Login required when generating Crytal Report. SQL Server 08, VS 08

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, database-connection

When o load my Crystal Report onto a `CrystalReportViewer` i am prompted with Database Login with disabled (fixed) server name.

Now when i load the same report on my development machine, it works fine. but when i deploy the C# application on a different machine, i am always prompted for a DB Login. (where the server-name is the one used on my development machine and its static (i cant change it)

i have been trying to find a solution for weeks now and with no luck.

i am using a `DataTable` as a report source :

> MyReport.SetDataSource(MyDataTable)

i have tried most of the online solutions that i searched for.

i have tried passing the DB Login information at run-time

i have installed the SQL Native Client

i have tried to pass a `DataSet` instead of a `DataTable`

All with no luck

it also came to my understanding that when i load a report with 1 database table inside i am not prompted for database login (i.e. my datable will be filled with one table form the database : `"Select * From SomeTable"` when i use an inner join query i am prompted for the login

Any thoughts anyone on how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i have finally solved it i was using

```
cr.SetDatabaseLogon(Username, Password, @Server, DBNAME);
```

i replaced that code and passed the login information for each table used in the report

T

```
ableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
                TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                ConnectionInfo CInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                //GET THE SERVER INFORMATION
                DataTable DT = b.GetServerInfo();
                CInfo.ServerName = DT.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                CInfo.DatabaseName = DT.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                CInfo.UserID = DT.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                CInfo.Password = DT.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                Tables CrTables = cr.Database.Tables;
                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
                {
                    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = CInfo;
                    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
                }


                frmReportViewer ff = new frmReportViewer();
                ff.crViewer.LogOnInfo = crtableLogoninfos;
                ff.crViewer.ReportSource = cr;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set the property 'ReportSource' of object CrystalReportViewer to Nothing:

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing

to avoid previewing of any report set by default at design-time.